# How to make lines with Julia using Gadfly (Facility location problem)?

Tags: julia, line, gadfly

Im trying to make the facility location problem algorithm ,and i got a possible solution ,  but dont know how to graph it,now im trying to use different layers by each binding line between the supplying center and the supplied point.For example , to make this two lines im using 2 different layers, with two different vectors: Supply point [1,1] and supplied points [5,2] and [2,6] as example:

```
using Gadfly
plot(layer(x=[1,5], y=[1,2],Geom.point, Geom.path),layer(x=[1,2], y=[1,6],Geom.point, Geom.path))
```

But, my issue is that i need to make it with hundreds of lines alike,many supplying and supplied points ,so i dont think proper to make a layer by bind.
So , when try to make something like:

```
x=[1,2],[3,4]
y=[3,4],[2,4]
plot(layer(x[:], y[:],Geom.point, Geom.path))
```

I get a error. Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your example you assigned `x=[1,2],[3,4]` which creates a *tuple of arrays* and Gadfly doesn't know how to handle it.

You'll need to provide the arrays as named parameters to plot:

```
xc = [0,1,0,-1,0,4,0,-2,0,-2]
yc = [0,3,0,-2,0,1,0,2,0,-2]
plot(x=xc, y=yc, Geom.path, Geom.point)
```

The important part if you use `Geom.path` is to follow back to the supplying center, which is the point (0,0) in my example but could be any other. You'll need to prepare and interleave the data (`x` and `y`) on your own.

Another way would be to use `Geom.vector`:

```
# coordinate system and scales are necessary for Geom.vector
coord = Coord.cartesian(xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5)
xsc  = Scale.x_continuous(minvalue=-5, maxvalue=5)
ysc  = Scale.y_continuous(minvalue=-5, maxvalue=5)

# prepare the points you want to show
xend = [1,-1,4,-2,-2]
yend = [3,-2,1,2,-2]

# create the supplying center (1,2)
x = fill(1,length(xend))
y = fill(2,length(yend))

#plot everything
plot(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend,xsc,ysc,Geom.vector,coord)
```

Helpful documentation on Gadfly: http://gadflyjl.org/stable/index.html (take a look at Gallery->Geometries)

Comment: but how you could graph more than one supply point i get error with that,could be something obvious to notice but dont see it regards

Comment: would the supply points be connected to a different set of points?

Answer (score 0):

See also [Geom.segment](http://gadflyjl.org/dev/gallery/geometries/#[Geom.segment](@ref)-1), which is like `Geom.vector` but without an arrow, and doesn't need explicit scales.